# Create 2 or more text files with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, razor

I have created a web app which creates 1 text file. Inside this text file it is created 1000 rows with the same word "TRY AGAIN". After this each 50 rows I put a random code which means in 1000 rows, 20 rows are random.
This is my code:

```
static Random randNum = new Random();
    public static string Random(int ran)
    {
        string _charachters = "ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

        char[] chars = new char[ran];
        int allowedCharCount = _charachters.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < ran; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = _charachters[(int)((_charachters.Length) * randNum.NextDouble())];
        }

        return new string(chars);
    }


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string pathCreate = @"C:\" + TextBox3.Text + ".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(pathCreate))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(pathCreate))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= int.Parse(TextBox1.Text); i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("TRY AGAIN.");
                }
            }
        }


        string pathRandom = @"C:\" + TextBox3.Text + ".txt";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathRandom);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += int.Parse(TextBox2.Text))
        {
            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("TRY AGAIN.", Random(int.Parse("7")));
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(pathRandom, lines);
}
```

Now I want to create 2 ore more text files with one click of a button. And on each text file there will be random codes (not duplicates). Any idea?
Thank You.

Comment: No need to be offensive. Comment flagged for moderation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is late in my country and my brain barely works. :P

```
for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            string pathKrijo = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\KODET\" + j.ToString() + ".txt";
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(pathKrijo))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Provo Përsëri.");
                }
            }

            string pathKodFitues = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\KODET\" + j.ToString() + ".txt";
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathKodFitues);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 10)
            {
                lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("Provo Përsëri.", Random(int.Parse("7")));
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(pathKodFitues, lines);
        }
```